# Validating an Excel file in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a Rails app which allows users to upload Excel files which need to be validated according to some pre-defined rules. For eg. sheet 1 contains two columns, a numerical id and a name; sheet 2 contains three other columns etc..

Are there any Ruby gems/libraries that can help in doing these validations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really hard to do that by yourself. I highly recommend [Spreadsheet](http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/) gem.

Comment: I am using the roo gem which uses the spreadsheet gem internally for Excel files.

Comment: Did the validations using roo. Thanks!